# Restart a service and check its status

Tags: logging, windows, powershell

I have written this script to stop and start a specific service and check if it was able to load and unload applications tasks correctly, by checking a status in application log. Also it writes a log which tells the sequence of events in the script.

I have following questions related to my code :

1. I feel this is not an efficient way of writing a code and I could minimize the code length and performance of my script
2. What possible test cases should this script have? I have tested this few times and it does the job which I require at the moment.

```
Function Get-MicroStrategyIntelligenceCheck{
<#
.SYNOPSIS
HealthCheck for the MicroStrategy Intelligence Service

.DESCRIPTION
Get the basic HealthCheck for the MicroStrategy Intelligence Service, This function checks the health of the service by looking into MicroStrategy DSSErrors.log 

.PARAMETER computername
-action

.EXAMPLE
Get-MicroStrategyIntelligenceCheck -action stop
Get-MicroStrategyIntelligenceCheck -action start
#>
        [cmdletbinding()]
        param(
            [parameter(Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineBypropertyname = $true)]
            [string]$action
            )
    BEGIN{}
    PROCESS{   
            $file_Path = "${env:CommonProgramFiles(x86)}"  + "\MicroStrategy\Log\DSSErrors.log"              
            $Date = $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            if($action -eq 'stop'){
                                    $message = 'MicroStrategy Intelligence Server shutdown normally'
                                    $outmessage = 'stopped' 
                                    Write-Output 'stopped'
                                    $run_command = 'Stop-Service "MicroStrategy Intelligence Server" -WarningAction Continue -ErrorAction stop'
                                    }
            elseif($action -eq 'start'){
                                        $message = 'Projects Loading Finished: projects'
                                        $outmessage = 'running'
                                        Write-Output 'running'
                                        $run_command = 'Start-Service "MicroStrategy Intelligence Server" -WarningAction Continue -ErrorAction stop'
                                        }
            else{                     
                Logging_Script -message "Incorrect parameter '$action', Accepted values are start and stop" -level ERROR
                exit
                }                      
            $service_exec_date = $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
            Logging_Script -message "Action Initiated : service '$action' "
            Logging_Script -message "Action Initiated : Invoking expression '$run_command' "

            Try{
                Invoke-Expression $run_command
                }
            catch{
                  Logging_Script -message "Service ccommand $run_command failed to complete" -level ERROR
                  exit
                 }

            Logging_Script -message "Waiting for Service to change to '$action' with 90s timeout" -level WARN
            (get-service 'MicroStrategy Intelligence Server').WaitForStatus($outmessage,'00:01:30')
            $service_exec_complete = $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
            Logging_Script -message "Service status changed to '$action' , Starting MicroStrategy DSS Service Log check"             

            Logging_Script -message "Searching DSS log for '$message'"
            $service_message= Get-Content $file_Path | Where-Object {$_.contains($Date)} | Select-String -AllMatches $message             
            $LastMessage = $service_message | select -Last 1
            $extracted_date = $LastMessage -split "\[HOST:"                            

            if($extracted_date[0] -gt $service_exec_date){
                                                          #Write-Output "$($extracted_date[0]) is greater than $($service_exec_date)"
                                                          Logging_Script -message "Service $action status healthy."
                                                          }
            else {
                  #Write-Output "$($service_exec_date) is greater than $($extracted_date[0])"
                  Logging_Script -message "Service $action status not healthy." -level ERROR
                 }
            }
    END{}
  }


Function Logging_Script{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param(
            [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
                    [string]$message,
            [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
            [validateset("INFO","WARN","ERROR")]
            [string]$level = "INFO"
            )
    BEGIN{
          $ScriptlogFile  = "E:\Scripts\CLS_MicroStrategyIntelligenceServer.log"
          if(!(Test-Path $ScriptlogFile)){
                                         New-Item -ItemType File -Path $ScriptlogFile
                                         }
        }
    PROCESS{            
            $eventtime = $(Get-Date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
            $line = "$eventtime : [Host: $env:Computername ] $level - $message"
            Add-Content -Path $ScriptlogFile -Value $line
            }
    END{}
}


# Calling the service by stopping and starting it.
Get-MicroStrategyIntelligenceCheck -action stop
Get-MicroStrategyIntelligenceCheck -action start
```